Real part of operator question
I have a question regarding one equality, namely
$$Q\Re (e^{2i\theta}A)+\Re (e^{2i\theta}A)Q=\Re (e^{2i\theta}(QA+AQ))$$
In the paper I am reading, $Q$ is a positive operator and $A=|A|U|A|$ where $|A|=(A^{*}A)^{\frac{1}{2}}$, that is $|A|$ is a positive operator.
It makes sense that for $a\in {R}, a\cdot \Re (x)=\Re (ax)$ but how does one prove this for an operator setting?

By “for $a \in R$”, did you mean $a$ to be a real number or a self-adjoint operator? In the first case $a \cdot \mathfrak{R}(x) = \mathfrak{R}(ax)$ follows easily from the definition of real parts, while in the second case it’s just not true.

(As for the equality for the beginning, just write down the definition of real parts and use it to expand out both sides of the equation.)

I thought that there was something else, its just the definition lol, sorry for asking such a dumb question. I was lazy to write it out to check at the first look. @DavidGao
